# Terraforming/adding a magnetic field on the moon:Could it affect our planet?

Tags: atmosphere, terraforming

Many people write about terraforming of the moon(including me). Often ,it is not only about changing the atmosphere,but adding a magnetic field.However,we know that the moon does affect the Earth,and there are theories .So my question is:when we add a magnetic field and/or change moon's atmosphere,will it affect our planet negatively?

From what i know,changing our natural satelite's magnetic field could be dangerous.

Comment: [Interesting related article](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2020/10/201015173133.htm). If we assume that the moon once had an ancient core dynamo, then what affects, if any, would that have had on the planet in the distant past? Are you assuming a field only as strong as that ancient core dynamo would have been, had it existed? Or are you assuming a field that is stronger? Please tell us either the purpose of the field you're creating or the strength of the field. Thanks!

Comment: Just going to throw in my two cents... I don't know why but I suddenly have flashbacks to the "Blink of an Eye" episode of StarTrek Voyager. In that episode the ship basically screwed up the magnetic field of the planet and became the third pole, throwing the planet out of sync with the rest of the universe. For every second on the ship several days or weeks pass on the planet.

Comment: @JBH I just thought of a magnetic field that would be suitable for human habitation or some other known lifeforms.I do not know what kind of strength would that be,Something  more Earth-like i guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I don't think there would be any negative effects**

Any magntic interference from the moon would not come anywhere close to the strength of the solar wind which bombards the planet all day every day.

[image: Moon orbit vs earth's magnetic field]

Earth would pass through the Moon's magnetotail & vice-versa, possibly giving rise to some interesting visual effects as charged particles are chanelled through one field and then into the other, you might see the aurora borealis a little further south on some nights. But the moon & earth in this case would be complementing each other by acting as additional barriers against the solar wind, further deflecting incoming particles - if anything it might actually be beneficial overall. Check this out:

https://scitechdaily.com/moon-shielding-was-critical-to-earths-ability-to-maintain-its-atmosphere/

It is possible that it could give rise to some radio interference which would necessitate redesigning some artificial satellites, but that's a technological hurdle which would be easily overcome.